# How are operations of imaging satellite constellations scheduled?

Tags: satellite-constellation, operations

Checking Wikipedia, I see that there are a number of Earth-imaging constellations of 5+ satellites, with Planet Labs' and Spire Global's being the largest with 80+ satellites.

What is the usual approach for scheduling the operations for such constellations?

I suppose that they must:

- consider multiple satellites
- follow an heuristic approach that is probably less random than a genetic algorithm
- consider both the instruments operations and the communications with ground stations
- consider the availability schedule of ground stations
- consider exchange of data between satellites
- produce fast results if a new scheduling is needed, or allow for dynamically introducing new operations
- etc

So although the operations may be simpler than navigation or communication constellations, it still seems very complex and computationally-demanding.

Is there a general approach that is commonly used?

Comment: Can you give an example of a large imaging constellation managed by NASA?

Comment: Oops! You are right. I made a few changes here and there, after checking the actual list of constellations according to Wikipedia. Planet Labs and Global Spire seem to be the largest ones with 80+, although smaller ones of 5-10 satellites must also face a similar problem, maybe even more restrained given their longer revisit times.